How does JVM Clojure store captured environments of closures under the hood?
When I define a function that captures some of its variables in the outer scope, such as below, how does Clojure (on a JVM host) actually store the captured environment?
(let [small-datastructure (calculate-small-thing)
      large-datastructure (calculate-large-thing)]
  (if *feeling-lucky*
    (fn capturing-closure [] (do-other-thing small-datastructure))
    (use-data large-datastructure))

In particular, the function capturing-closure only references the small-datastructure, but not the large-datastructure. When I return capturing-closure from this code, will the large-datastructure still be referenced by capturing-closure, or will it be released to garbage collection?
I'm open to both direct answers or suggestions for how to accurately measure this.


how does Clojure (on a JVM host) actually store the captured environment?

Every function becomes a class, every captured thing becomes a member field.

When I return capturing-closure from this code, will the large-datastructure still be referenced by capturing-closure, or will it be released to garbage collection?

The latter.

suggestions for how to accurately measure this.

You can compile the code and inspect the generated .class files in whatever way you prefer.
Or you can use https://github.com/clojure-goes-fast/clj-java-decompiler.

Answering my own question -- though I'd still appreciate an answer based on insights into Clojure/JVM internals!
I hooked up a small experiment using (System/gc) to force GC, and using a weak reference to check whether the objects still exist on the heap after GC:
(ns gc-test
  (:import [java.lang.ref WeakReference]))

(defn calculate-small-thing [] (vec (range 10)))

(defn calculate-large-thing [] (vec (range 10000000)))

(def closure-use (atom nil))

(defn test-closure-gc []
  (dotimes [i 10]
    (println "Test iteration:" i)
    (let [[weak-small-ref, weak-large-ref]
          (let [small-datastructure (calculate-small-thing)
                weak-small-ref (WeakReference. small-datastructure)
                large-datastructure (calculate-large-thing)
                weak-large-ref (WeakReference. large-datastructure)
                capturing-closure (fn [] (reduce + small-datastructure))]
            ;; Store the closure to prevent it from being garbage collected
            (reset! closure-use capturing-closure)
            ;; Return our weak references
            [weak-small-ref weak-large-ref])]
      ;; Force garbage collection
      (System/gc)
      ;; Sleep briefly to allow GC to complete
      (Thread/sleep 100)
      ;; Sanity-check that small-datastructure is not collected
      (println "Is small-datastructure collected?"
               (nil? (.get weak-small-ref)))
      ;; Check if large-datastructure has been garbage collected
      (println "Is large-datastructure collected?"
               (nil? (.get weak-large-ref))))))

;; Run the test
(test-closure-gc)

The output shows that the small-datastructure remains referenced as expected, and the large-datastructure gets reliably collected:
Test iteration: 0
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 1
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 2
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 3
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 4
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 5
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 6
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 7
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 8
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true
Test iteration: 9
Is small-datastructure collected? false
Is large-datastructure collected? true

